# Survival plot with years instead of days as x-axis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I try to plot a survival plot with `survplot` showing years on the x-axis instead of days (dod: date of death/end f'up; dob: date of birth; dead: status; start: begin of observation; exposure: category of exposure).

The dates in the original dataset are R date format - converted into days by `as.numeric`.

```
library(rms)

n <- 1000

sex   <- as.factor(round(runif(n,0,1),0))
dob   <- as.Date(round(runif(n,-9000,-4000)), origin="1970-01-01")
dead  <- as.factor(rnorm(n,0.5,1)>1)
start <- as.Date(round(runif(n,3000,4000)), origin="1970-01-01")

dod  <- rep(as.Date(15000, origin="1970-01-01"),n)

df <- data.frame(cbind(sex,dob,start,dod,dead))

df$dod[which(df$dead==T)] <- as.Date(round(runif(length(which(df$dead==T)), 5000,15000)), origin="1970-01-01")

df$surv <- Surv(as.numeric(df$start), as.numeric(df$dod), origin=as.numeric(df$dob), df$dead)

ddist <- datadist(df); options(datadist="ddist")

f <- cph(surv ~ sex, data=df, x=T, y=T, surv=T)
survplot(f, sex)
```

This works well - but the x-axis is in days and not in years. How can I change this?

Comment: Please include sample data with `dput`.

Comment: I would love to, but I can't make my dataset publicly available. Is there a good sample dataset for survival analyses?

Comment: Then tell us how your dataset looks like: How are the dates stated?

Comment: If you can't share your data, it is common to provide code to generate representative synthetic (fake) data.

Comment: Also: Is there a reason why you're using `cph` from `rms` instead of `coxph` from `survival`? It seems you're mixing methods from two different R packages for no good reason.

Comment: I use `rms` for all my analyses - and `survplot` and `cph` are both from this package'. The documentation for `cph` uses `Surv` (and `rms` does load survival).

Comment: I'm reasonably experienced with the `rms` and `Hmisc` functions and have looked at the documentation for `units` and the code for `Hmisc::units<-` and think you need to take a more hackish path. Trying to reassign units to `time2` failed. Suggest converting to using `Surv` with a single time parameter given as an interval rather than `start` and `stop`. You would need to take the difference between start and stop, and then divide by 365.25.

Comment: Using only one time does not allow me to use the origin - which I would like to use if possible.